# Customize ImageField.image.url

Tags: django, image

I have a Django model for a user-uploaded photo. It contains a field defined as

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo_image_files')
    @property
       def name(self):
          return filename_without_extension
    ...
```

and settings.py defines

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

This means images are saved in `/media/photo_image_files/`. I would like to have JPEG files accessible at `/jpeg/:filename` and hide the actual path to the images from visitors. I have defined the corresponding view and url. However, now `{{ photo.image.url }}` predictably points to `/media/photo_image_files/filename.jpg`. As a workaround, I include images as

```
<img src="/jpeg/{{ photo.name }}" />
```

But that means I specify the location twice, in urls.py and in the template. How can I customise the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass `ImageField` and define your own `.url()` method:

```
class JpegImageField(ImageField):
    @property
    def url(self):
        return "/jpeg/{name}".format(name=self.name)
```

and use the new field class instead of regular `ImageField`:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    image = JpegImageField(upload_to='photo_image_files')
```